# Does was6-maven-plugin support Java 1.8?

Tags: websphere

We are upgrading to Java 1.8 and the was6-maven-plugin is failing.  It mentions 1.8, but I have been unable to determine if it is a configuration issue or if the plugin does not support 1.8.  I cannot find any good documentation on the plugin, either.

Has anyone used this plugin with Java 1.8?  Specifically it's the ejbdeploy goal, in case it makes a difference.

Comment: Are you using WAS v6? If so then the version of ejbdeploy would not run using a Java 8 VM. If the was6-maven-plugin were using the maven JVM that would explain it.

Comment: We are using WAS 8.5.5 with JVM 1.8.  We were previously using 1.7 and the plugin worked.

Comment: It'll likely depend on the WAS version. If the plugin is using the maven JVM, but a version of ejbdeploy that won't run on Java 8 you'll get problems. What version of WAS are you using?